# How to implement my for loop and call my function to get a result in my Ridge regression model?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am a novice and I start in the data and I try to predict thanks to a regression model the price of a house, a price exercise on kaggle file: train.csv , i'm going to explore data

```
     import numpy as np
     import pandas as pd
     from sklearn import preprocessing
     from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
     from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score , cross_val_predict, cross_validate
     from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
     from sklearn.linear_model import Ridge, LassoCV
     import seaborn as sns
     import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
     from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
     from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
     from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
     from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
     from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
     from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
     %matplotlib inline

     data  = pd.read_csv('train.csv', index_col = 0)
     pd.set_option('display.max_row',80)
     pd.set_option('display.max_column',80)
     hp = data.copy()
     
    hp = hp.apply(lambda x: x.fillna(0) if x.dtype.kind in 'biufc' else x.fillna(hp.mean()))
    hp.isna().sum()
    
   from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
   numeric_features = hp.select_dtypes(exclude = ['object'])
   numeric_transformer = Pipeline(steps=[
               ('imputer', SimpleImputer(strategy='median')),
               ('scaler', StandardScaler())])

 categorical_features  = hp.select_dtypes('object')
 categorical_features= categorical_features.fillna('Z')
 categorical_transformer  = 
 OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore')
 preprocessor = ColumnTransformer(
     transformers=[
       ('num', numeric_transformer, numeric_features),
       ('cat', categorical_transformer, 
        categorical_features)])
  
y = numeric_features['SalePrice']
X = numeric_features.drop('SalePrice', axis=1)


X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=5)
scaler = preprocessing.StandardScaler().fit(X)
X_train_scaled = scaler.transform(X_train)
X_test_scaled  = scaler.transform(X_test)


    
 def rmse_cv(model):
 rmse= np.sqrt(-cross_val_score(clf, X_train_scaled, y_train,  
      scoring="neg_mean_squared_error", cv = 5))
 return(rmse)
```

How to implement my for loop and call my function to get a result in my Ridge regression model?

```
  coefs = []
  rmse  = []
  alphas = [0.01, 0.05 , 0.1, 0.3, 0.8, 1, 5,10, 15, 30,50]
  for a in alphas:
      ridge = Ridge(alpha=a, fit_intercept=True)
      ridge.fit(X_train_scaled, y_train)
      coefs.append(ridge.coef_)
      rmse_cv()
```

Answer (score 0):

In the [documentation of sklearn](http://%20https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.Ridge.html#sklearn.linear_model.Ridge.predict), a method that returns the predictions have been included.

Another [online source](https://hydra.smith.edu/%7Ejcrouser/SDS293/labs/lab10-py.html), smith.edu, explains how to use the method with an example.

Here is how you can integrate them into your solution:

```
coefs = []
rmse  = []
alphas = [0.01, 0.05 , 0.1, 0.3, 0.8, 1, 5,10, 15, 30,50]
for a in alphas:
    ridge = Ridge(alpha=a, fit_intercept=True)
    ridge.fit(X_train_scaled, y_train)
    pred = ridge.predict(X_test)  
    coefs.append(ridge.coef_)
    rmse.append = mean_squared_error(y_test, pred)          # Calculate the test MSE
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but I want to create this loop to see the results of each alphas in order to learn how to determine the best result and I cannot see where the problem lies.

Comment: Maybe you would want to get the test results and evaluate them to calculate the performance for each alpha in each step of the loop.

Comment: For that, I would recommend reading the second link I have shared, they calculate the mse over there.

Comment: Thank you for this solution which seems to be suitable, but I went further by integrating it into my function and it seems to be a problem

Comment: what is the problem? more details needed